# Combining multiple SELECT/WHERE into a result with multiple columns with alias names

Tags: postgresql, pivot

I have a Timescale DB / PostgreSQL table (DataTable) which looks like this

[image: DataTable example]

I'm trying to find a query which would return different columns for different subsystem/metrics combination like this

[image: Query Result]

Furthermore I would like to reduce the amount of requested data points using the Timescale DB function time_bucket_gapfill() to keep the response time low for big time ranges. I would also like to use different aggregation functions for different subsystem/metric combinations.
I use the queried data to plot the curves in Grafana.
What is the most time efficient way to achieve that?

At the moment I use separate queries for each metric which quickly gets very slow. For the example the queries could look like that

```
SELECT
    time_bucket_gapfill('30s',time,start=>'2021-07-19T09:06:26.605Z',finish=>'2021-07-19T20:11:12.340Z') AS "time",
    max(value) AS "Latitude"
FROM DataTable
WHERE
    time BETWEEN '2021-07-19T09:06:26.605Z' AND '2021-07-19T20:11:12.340Z' AND
    subsystem = 'position' AND
    metric = 'lat'
GROUP BY 1,metric,subsystem
ORDER BY time
```

```
SELECT
    time_bucket_gapfill('30s',time,start=>'2021-07-19T09:06:26.605Z',finish=>'2021-07-19T20:11:12.340Z') AS "time",
    min(value) AS "Longitude"
FROM DataTable
WHERE
    time BETWEEN '2021-07-19T09:06:26.605Z' AND '2021-07-19T20:11:12.340Z' AND
    subsystem = 'position' AND
    metric = 'lon'
GROUP BY 1,metric,subsystem
ORDER BY time
```

```
SELECT
    time_bucket_gapfill('30s',time,start=>'2021-07-19T09:06:26.605Z',finish=>'2021-07-19T20:11:12.340Z') AS "time",
    avg(value) AS "Temperature"
FROM DataTable
WHERE
    time BETWEEN '2021-07-19T09:06:26.605Z' AND '2021-07-19T20:11:12.340Z' AND
    subsystem = 'health' AND
    metric = 'temperature'
GROUP BY 1,metric,subsystem
ORDER BY time
```

I would much appreciate if somebody could point me in the right direction.

**Update:**

Using the FILTER clause as suggested by @Charlieface doesn't work for me, because it doesn't remove the other rows but instead places NULLs there. Here an example with some real data (the example before was using simplified data and names).

[image]

I also noticed that the timestamps of the metrics belonging together have tiny differences which would prevent different metrics being on the same row, but that is easy to changes in the unit which feeds the data into the DB.

**Update 2:**

The timestamps issue was fixed and the WHERE statement was added again as suggested by @Charlieface, but there are still NULL in the data which makes Grafana plot the data points without lines in between.

[image]

I would like the result to look like this instead.

[image]

**Update 3:**

I missed that @Charlieface answer only groups by time. If I do that, then I get the result I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use conditional aggregation for this.**

In PostgreSQL you can use the `FILTER` clause.

> In other DBMSs you can use a condition inside the aggregation
> `avg(case when ... then value end)`

```
SELECT
    time_bucket_gapfill('30s', time, start => '2021-07-19T09:06:26.605Z', finish => '2021-07-19T20:11:12.340Z') AS "time",
    max(value) FILTER (WHERE subsystem = 'position' AND metric = 'lat') AS "Latitude",
    min(value) FILTER (WHERE subsystem = 'position' AND metric = 'lon') AS "Longitude",
    avg(value) FILTER (WHERE subsystem = 'health' AND metric = 'temperature') AS "Temperature"
FROM DataTable
WHERE
    time BETWEEN '2021-07-19T09:06:26.605Z' AND '2021-07-19T20:11:12.340Z'
  AND (subsystem = 'position' AND metric IN ('lat', 'lon') OR
       subsystem = 'health' AND metric = 'temperature')
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY time;
```

Comment: The FILTER clause doesn't work for me, because it adds NULL for all subsystem/metrics rows which were filtered out (see "Update" in my Question). The NULLs in the data causes Grafana to plot data points not connected by lines.

Comment: Oh then you need to add the `WHERE` filters back in, but include all of the ones you want together. Have modified

Comment: There are still NULL in the query reply (see "Update 2" in my question).

Comment: You haven't copied my query properly, I only have `GROUP BY 1` not `GROUP BY 1, metric, subsystem`. This is obviously dependent on those timestamps being exact;y identical

Comment: Oh, I missed that. Grouping only by time gives me the exact query result I wanted. Thank you very much. This was very helpful.